# How can I globally set Oracle fetch size in my Scala Play (Anorm) application?

Tags: oracle, scala, jdbc, playframework

Our DBAs would like me to increase the fetch size from the JDBC's default (10). Is there a way to do this globally via `application.conf`, JDBC URL or similar?

My DB calls essentially look like

```
object SomeController extends Controller {
  def someMethod(acronym: String) = Action { implicit request =>
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
      val cust = SQL("""select whatever....  where acronym = {acronym}""").on("acronym" -> acronym).apply()
```

But there's a lot of them over many controllers and methods.

What can be done to have a central setting?

Comment: If you're using Weblogic JDBC, maybe you can look at weblogic.oci.cacheRows which increases your fetch array size...

Comment: we're using plain old ojdbc6.jar and the app is deployed with the embedded netty server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching through the Oracle JDBC jar, I found:

```
ojdbc6-unjar $ cat ./oracle/jdbc/defaultConnectionProperties.properties
# This properties file sets the default value for connection properties.
# Entries in this file override the predefined defaults as specified
# in the JavaDoc for oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection. These defaults are
# themselves overridden by any values set via -D which are overridden
# by values passed in the Properties argument to getConnection.
#
```

This bit and the Javadoc do a very bad job at explaining of how to derive the actual parameter name, but after many tries of various case styles, package names etc. I found this to be working:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Doracle.jdbc.defaultRowPrefetch=1000" \
   ./activator -Dconfig.file=conf/xe.conf run
```

This will make boneCP use a reasonable fetch size without any code change.

Answer (score 1):

`defaultRowPrefresh` is an Oracle JDBC driver property than can be set to change from the default of 10 ([Table 4-2 Connection Properties Recognized by Oracle JDBC Drivers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/basic.htm#g1028323))

While not explicitly documented, it looks like custom JDBC properties are done under the `datasource` key (see [this](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/b65a55a9bd6765fab793dada704e0bb59f02b6a6/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/HikariCPModule.scala#L102) and [this](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#initialization))

So something like `db.default.datasource.defaultRowsPrefetch="100"` should work.

Comment: Thanks Tony! It turns out that this application is in Play 2.3.x still and I think that predates having the Hikari pool. I'll try to update and test it, looks promising.

Comment: Unfortunately I had some unrelated issues with upgrading Play and couldn't  test it, but I'm pretty confident it would work with Hikari (Play >= 2.4). I'm posting a -D jvm flag workaroudn for 2.3 as separate answer